# Python: Integration of Interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, numerical-integration

I've got some question I cant solve:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
from scipy.integrate import quad
import pylab as pl

x = ([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,...,4550,4560])
y = ([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,2,3,2,1,2,1,2,...,8,6,5,7,11,6,7,10,6,5,8,13,6,8,8,3])
s = UnivariateSpline(x, y, k=5, s=5)
xs = np.linspace(0, 4560, 4560)
ys = s(xs)
```

This is my code for making some Interpolation over some data.
In addition, I plotted this function.

But now I want to integrate it (from zero to infinity).

I tried

```
results = integrate.quad(ys, 0, 99999)
```

but it didnt work.

Can you give me some hints (or solutions) please? thanks

Comment: You don't need to put parentheses around the lists, `x = [0,10,...,4560]` is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Pierre GM said, you have to give a function for quad (I think also you can use `np.inf` for the upper bound, though here it doesn't matter as the splines go to 0 quickly anyways). However, what you want is:

```
s.integral(0, np.inf)
```

Since this is a spline, the `UnivariateSpline` object already implements an integral that should be better and faster.

Comment: ok, thanks for the explanation. But what is the return value of this function? How can I convert it to a function to display with "plot()"?

Comment: Hmmm, I guess you want to plot the antiderivative, not sure if there is a nice way to do this short of calculating s.integral(0, val) for lots of val's.

Comment: what if I want to do exactly the same in C? Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation of `quad`, you need to give a function as first argument, followed by the lower and upper bounds of the integration range, and some extra arguments for your function (type `help(quad)` in your shell for more info.

You passed an array as first argument (`ys`), which is why it doesn't work. You may want to try something like:

```
results = quad(s, xs[0], xs[-1])
```

or

```
results = quad(s, 0, 9999)
```